# Trying to add a suffix(string) to the end of each WebElement in a list

Tags: python, selenium

I'm currently trying to verify whether some checkboxes are checked based on the word following them. If the line contains the word 'Elephant' it will go back to the beginning of that row and find the checkbox associated with it. My problem is that there are multiple lines that contain elephant and so I need to find all those elements.

I'm not able to tack `'is_selected()'` onto the end of `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Elephant')]/preceding::td[1]/span/input[1]")`

Because I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '.is_selected'`

So I've come to the conclusion that to get around this I need to attach `.is_selected()` to the end of each list item and then I can go from there verifying them.

Here is what I've tried:

```py
CheckBoxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Elephant')]/preceding::td[1]/span/input[1]")

Checkboxes = [x + ".is_selected" for x in CheckBoxes]

print(Checkboxes)
```

The error I get when I run the above is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WebElement' and 'str'
```

Also, if anyone has a better way to do this than turning these elements into a list I'd love some advice on that

**UPDATE:**

Here is what I went with instead that doesn't answer the original question, but does solve my problem.

```py
try:
    for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Elephant')]/preceding::td[1]/span/input[1]"):
        On = element.is_selected()

        if On is True:
            print("Elephant: Checked")
            print("\n")
        else:
            print("Elephant: UNCHECKED")
            print("\n")

except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

**please share the snapshot of the dom if my the below suggestion doesn't solve your problem**
First of all you are using find_elements that returns list of elements, and that's the reason why is_selected() is failing with the below error
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '.is_selected`
Assuming you verified the xpath in the browser and you are able to point all of the expected fields, here is the following code. 
Lets say all checkboxes are prsent in CheckBoxes variable

```
for checkbox in CheckBoxes:
    assert checkbox.is_selected(), "checkbox is with text elephant is not selected"
```